# Why is it not using my overloaded operator for ++?

Tags: c++, operators, operator-overloading, increment

I have created an overloaded operator for ++ in my .hpp file and then a function which calls it also in the .hpp file. The .cpp file then calls the function but when the function hit the ++ code it doesnt eneter the overloaded operator but instead used the default operation operator for ++. Why isnt it using my overloaded operator?

Here is the operators for ++:

```
iterator& operator ++ () {  // pre-increment
        std::list<value_type>::iterator i = listOfValues.begin();
        advance(i,1);
        return &*i;
    }

    Square_List operator ++ (int) { // post-increment
        std::list<value_type>::iterator i = listOfValues.begin();
        advance(i,1);
        return &*i;
    }
```

And here is the function using it:

```
template <typename A_>
void testerIncrement(A_ toInc)
{

    toInc = listOfValues.begin();
    cout << "\n" << *toInc;
    ++toInc;
    cout << "\n" << *toInc;
    ++toInc;
}
```

And lastly the call for the function in the .cpp file

```
ca.testerIncrement(ca.listOfValues.begin());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You overload the prefix increment operator ++ with either a nonmember function operator that has one argument of class type or a reference to class type, or with a member function operator that has no arguments.

It seems you are using non member operators. So your syntax should be
void operator++(iterator &); //prefix
and void operator++(Square_List, int); //postfix.